# App Store rejection - Support URL metadata

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, appstore-approval

Apple has rejected my app, saying:

> **Guideline 1.5 - Safety - Developer Information**
>
> The support URL specified in your app’s metadata does not properly navigate to the intended destination.

But the support URL of my app is properly navigating.

The support URL contains an email address on which users can mail if they have any issues and feedback.

What can I do for this issue?

Comment: have you checked in latest version of iOS? iOS 13.0 and later?

Comment: It is a metadata rejection, What do I need to check in iOS 13.0?

Comment: @Nikunj Can you please share your app support URL ?

Comment: My support URL contains an email address, which is in format of link(hyperlink), and I think the issue is because of that

Comment: I found my email in support URL contains a half link(hyperlink), it does not contain underline before @ in my email, it contains underline in @gmail.com

Comment: may it be an issue?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I have attached the screenshot of the support URL, please check it and let me know if there is any issue

Comment: They write "The support URL specified in your app’s metadata does not properly navigate to the intended destination" - maybe theres just a little problem with the link you've entered in App Store Connect. For example a leading whitespace or you forgot the last character by copy and pasting it in App Store connect input field. Also make sure theres no URL-Encoding problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I made changes in Support URL and make an email address clickable.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way to get around this support page requirement is creating a facebook page and setting up a messenger link inside the app.

Comment: Thanks for the support, but I want to provide email address for support, then which way would be easy?

Comment: Not sure why your app got rejected because I don't see any issue with the way you've set it up. Maybe problem is with the the non clickable email address. Also check if that page is publicly accessible.

Comment: Do you include the messenger link or the direct link to the facebook page as the support url after setting up a messenger link?